# Graphing a Line and two Points in 3D

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to graph a line with a white dot at one end and a green dot at the other end. This is what I have and it's not working. I can't figure out why.

```
x[t_] = 10000 - 0.05*t - (2*10^-6)*t^2;
y[t_] = -5000 + 0.001*t + (2*10^-6)*t^2;
z[t_] = -7000 + 0.001*t + (3*10^-6)*t^2;
Subscript[traj, lander] = {x[t_], y[t_], z[t_]};
Subscript[t, release] = Subscript[traj, lander][x[0], y[0], z[0]];
Solve[(10000 - 0.05*t - (2*10^-6)*t^2)^2/
6000^2 + (-5000 + 0.001*t + (2*10^-6)*t^2)^2/
3000^2 + (-7000 + 0.001*t + (3*10^-6)*t^2)^2/2500^2 == 1]
Subscript[t, land] = 42876.557480446856;
Plot3D[{Subscript[traj, lander], Subscript[t, release], 
Subscript[t, land]}, {x, 0, 6000}, {y, 0, 3000}, {z, 0, 2500}, 
PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick, Green, PointSize[1], White, 
PointSize[1]}]
```

Comment: It's great that you've included your code, properly formatted! However, there's so many syntax errors in there$-$and the code is so disconnected from what you say you're trying to do$-$that you need to give us more details about the problem. I do recommend reading some of the *Mathematica* tutorials and docs for some of the functions you are using (e.g. `Plot3D`) to make sure you understand what the proper syntax is and what you will be plotting.

Answer (score 3):

Using, David Stork's data, I prefer

```
greenpt = {1, 2, 5};
whitept = {3, 4, 2};
Graphics3D[{
  Gray, Tube[{greenpt, whitept}, .02],
  White, Sphere[whitept, .05],
  Green, Sphere[greenpt, .05]}, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: plot]

because it draws true 3D objects, which I think look better than 2D lines and points drawn in a 3D space.

But I don't think the OP wants a simple straight line. I suspect something like this is closer to what is wanted.

```
pts = Table[{-500 + 8 t, -700 + 10 t, 1000 - .5 t - t^2}, {t, 0, 10, .5}];
Graphics3D[
  {Gray, Tube[pts, Scaled[.0075]],
   White, Sphere[pts[[1]], Scaled[.02]],
   Green, Sphere[pts[[-1]], Scaled[.02]]},
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1],
  Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: curve]

Answer (score 1):

```
greenpt = {1, 2, 5};
whitept = {3, 4, 2};
Graphics3D[{Green, PointSize[0.1], Point[greenpt], 
           White, Point[whitept], 
           Thickness[0.02], Line[{greenpt, whitept}]},
 Background -> LightGray]
```

[image]